# "Missing compiler required member" error being thrown multiple times with almost no changes to code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Today after deploying some changes to a C# MVC site that I run, I went back to make some more modifications and came across this error:

> Missing compiler required member System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute..ctor

The error is a bit vague (other than it's description, obviously) as it doesn't give me a file, line, or column to reference, only the project. Also, it throws the error a total of 20 times. I only made three changes to the code between the time I deployed (it was completely functional at that time) and now. I reverted my changes and it is still throwing the same error which makes no sense to me.

I haven't found a lot of information on this error on SO or Google, other than [this guys](http://blog.flexforcefive.com/?p=105) solution and a couple references to some Mono project errors (I'm not using Mono). The solution the guy above gives requires adding a class definition that will allow the compiler to resolve the reference. I don't particularly want to do this because I haven't needed to do it up until this point and it will just muddy my code.

Just curious if anyone has run across this before.

Comment: Seems like you're using a C# 3.0 compiler but compiling against the .NET Framework 2.0. Check your assembly references.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This error usually means either your project is compiling against .NET 2.0 or you aren't referencing the correct version of System.Core.dll

For a near duplicate question, see [Error when using extension methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205644/error-when-using-extension-methods-in-c)

Comment: It actually turned out that I had a bad reference from an assembly that I was no longer using (Azure). I don't think the Azure assembly was compiled against .Net 2.0 but removing it fixed the issue. I'm not sure why this randomly came into being as I haven't touched anything related to my assemblies or .Net version (4.0) in quite some time. Alas, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Unity3D sets the compiler to .NET 2 by default (at time of writing). In player settings, change it to the newer.NET version to fix this issue.

Answer (score 252):

In my case it was because the project was not referencing `Microsoft.CSharp`. Once I added a reference to that assembly, it compiled just fine.

Comment: Solved the problem.

Comment: My problem was in a Unit Test using dynamic and Expando object. Referencing Microsoft.CSharp was the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I had dynamic type NewtonSoft etc  In .NetStandard Class library:
```
 string weatherjson = await GetAsync(url);
            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(weatherjson);
            dynamic temp = obj.main.temp;
```

I did Nuget Search for Microsoft.CSharp and installed that.
Library now builds :)

Q. Can I use this .NetStandard library in Linux app, given the Microsofct reference?

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason this was not obvious to me from the message!  I am tweaking a project written long ago and this reference stuff is frightening.  Makes one appreciate the relative clarity of Java which I normally use.

Comment: solved the issue

Answer (score 90):

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this, but I suddenly ran into this error after adding some code utilizing `dynamic` types and incorporating WebAPI into a project that originated as a TypeScript application in VS2013.  Simply adding a reference to Microsoft.CSharp resolved my issue.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Adding in dynamic mysteriously broke the project.

Comment: Same for me, using dynamic with .NetStandard2.0, I had to install C# Nuget for it to compile

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this situation as well today. In my case I was referencing the Newton.Json.Net dll v3.5 in my .NET 4.0 application. I realized that I wasnt even using this library, thus once I removed it from my references, it no longer gave me the compiler error.

Problem solved!!!

Comment: Same for me, Newton.Json.Net dll caused the problem!

Comment: In my case the reason was the wrong NET20 version of Microsoft's AntiXSSLibrary.dll. Replaced with NET35 - the error is gone.

Answer (score 7):

The actual error comes from the fact that your 2.0 assembly that causes the error contains this code:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

The Code Above allows the .NET 2.0 Assembly to use extension methods (see [Using extension methods in .NET 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522605/using-extension-methods-in-net-2-0)). While it confuses the compiler if you target .NET 4.0 and reference a 2.0 Assembly (containing above code) as the mscorlib.dll(4.0) contains the same class in the same namespace.

I fixed this

- by compiling the original 2.0 assembly again without the attribute targeting 4.0
- by removing the assembly (obviously)
- by adding a third Extension Attribute in the target you compile (it seems to overrule the referenced definitions)

Comment: This is exactly my issue, I'll try your instructions and post back.

Answer (score 6):

Writing this code somewhere in your project may solve your problem. It works for me

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Comment: where you write this code? you created a class in root of project?

Comment: @Alex I added a class called CompilerService to the root of my project with the code aboce and it worked.  Nice!

Answer (score 6):

Probably you use `dynamic` keyword In .NetStandard Class library project. If so, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp` library in the project. Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

NLog.dll 2.0 referenced from a .NET 4.0 project can cause this too.

Comment: NLog for .NET 2.0, referenced from a .NET 3.5 seems to give similar errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a correct solution, but I'll add my data point:

In my case the error is caused by referencing GoogleSearchAPINet20

Here is what happens:

- I close the solution that builds
- I open the solution again. It still builds
- As soon as I make any change and try to build, I get 19 "Missing compiler required member ..." errors
- I remove the reference to GoogleSearchAPINet20
- I add back the reference to GoogleSearchAPINet20
- I build the solution. It builds without errors
- I can now make code changes, build or perform any other actions with solution correctly as     long as my Visual Studio is open
- I close Visual Studio
- Repeat from step one

I'm not referencing System.Core.dll in my solution at all and my target framework is .NET 4.

I'm a bit annoyed at this point ...

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when trying to use async Tasks against .NET 4.0.  Updating Target Framework to 4.5.2 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same set of exceptions after I added some async methods to a winforms project. I needed to bump my .NET version from 4 to 4.5

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem occure when I add asynchronous method with async Task await in my .net4.0 project !

With previous versions of the .NET-Framework 4.5, you must install this package:

```
Install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async –pre
```

or

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack
```

more info on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) or [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack)