# How can i get value of "v" from this object + JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

How can i get value from data["v"] using JSON.Net

```
{
    "event": "ConnectTheDots",
    "data": "{ \"s\":\"wthr\",
           \"u\":\"F\",
           \"l\":\"Jaipur - The Pink City\",
           \"m\":\"Temperature\",
           \"o\":\"Nagarro\",
           \"v\": 3,
           \"d\":\"T" 
         }
    "published_at": "2016-06-08T11:48:32.772Z",
    "coreid": "2b0046000347343138333038",
    "guid": "2b0046000347343138333038",
    "timecreated": "2016-06-08T11:48:32.772Z",
    "location": "",
    "displayname": "",
    "organization": "",
    "value": "",
    "measurename": "",
    "unitofmeasure": "",
    "subject": ""
}
```

Comment: This JSON is not valid.  Try validating it at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize it as a dynamic object. See [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)

```
dynamic parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
var v = parsed.data.v;  // 3
```

Comment: i try your code but i'm getting `Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create' Application`

Comment: @PranavPatel You're missing an assembly reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22865030/3191599 Try adding a reference to `Microsoft.CSharp.dll`.

Comment: @PranavPatel Great! If it helped you, mind upvoting? :)