# Roslyn c# CSharpCompilation - Compiling Dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, roslyn

Roslyn compiler and dynamics --> I'm trying to compile a property only known at runtime.
The code works when compiling in Visual studio.  When compiling with Roslyn, the dynamic properties are 'unknown'.

In this example unit test I have a MyObject that inherits from DynamicObject. The properties are provided with a simple KeyValue Dictionary.

When using 'MyObject' in a hardcoded manner,  I can call the property Hello.  I can actually use any property at compile time..  Unexisting properties would error at runtime.  (expected behaviour)

When using 'MyObject' in code passed on to the roslyn compiler, I can't use any property on my dynamic object.  Here the property 'Hello' gives me the error:

```
CS1061 - 'MyObject' does not contain a definition for 'Hello' and no accessible extension method 'Hello' accepting a first argument of type 'MyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I missing?

Example unit test:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Testing {
    [TestClass]
    public class FullExampleTest {
        [TestMethod]
        public void HardCoded() {
            var map = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "Hello","Foo"},
                { "World","Bar"}
            };
            dynamic src = new MyObject(map);
            Console.WriteLine(src.Hello);

            Assert.AreEqual("Foo Bar", $"{src.Hello} {src.World}");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompileAtRuntime() {
            string code = @"
                using System;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
                using System.Dynamic;
                using System.IO;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Reflection;
                using Testing;

                namespace MyNamespace{{
                    public class MyClass{{
                        public static void MyMethod(MyObject src){{
                            Console.WriteLine(src.Hello);
                        }}
                    }}
                }}
           ";

            var ns = Assembly.Load("netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51");

            MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
            {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(ns.Location), //netstandard
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Object).Assembly.Location), //mscorlib
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(DynamicObject).Assembly.Location), //System.Core
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(RuntimeBinderException).Assembly.Location),//Microsoft.CSharp
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Action).Assembly.Location), //System.Runtime
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(FullExampleTest).Assembly.Location) // this assembly
            };


            var comp = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                assemblyName: Path.GetRandomFileName(),
                syntaxTrees: new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code) },
                references: references,
                options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            );

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                var result = comp.Emit(ms);
                if (!result.Success) {
                    var failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic => diagnostic.IsWarningAsError || diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                    foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{diagnostic.Id} - {diagnostic.GetMessage()}");
                    }
                }
                Assert.IsTrue(result.Success, "Compilation failure..");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyObject : DynamicObject {
        private IDictionary<string, string> _Map;

        public MyObject(IDictionary<string, string> map) {
            _Map = map;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
            Contract.Assert(binder != null);

            var ret = _Map.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out string value);
            result = value;
            return ret;
        }

        public override bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder,     object[] args, out object result) {
            Contract.Assert(binder != null);

            var ret = _Map.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out string value);
            result = value;
            return ret;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful for you  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864790/using-system-dynamic-in-roslyn

Comment: @So_oP I allready tried everything mentioned in that post..   Can you be more specific about what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dynamically-compiled code is not the same as your statically-compiled code. In your dynamically-compiled code, you've explicitly declared `src` as a `dynamic`. Your "hard-coded" example tries to treat is as a `MyObject`. You'd get the same problem if your hard-coded test looked like this:

```
    var src = new MyObject(map);
    Console.WriteLine(src.Hello);
```

So you can fix this by casting your `src` as `dynamic`:

```
public static void MyMethod(MyObject src){
    Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)src).Hello);
}
```

Or by declaring it as dynamic in the first place:

```
public static void MyMethod(dynamic src){
    Console.WriteLine(src.Hello);
}
```

Comment: ok, thank you very much!     #bangingMyHeadAgainstTheWall     A typical example of looking at the wrong places..

Comment: Glad I could help. Sometimes we just need a friend to look at the code with a fresh perspective. :-)