# Missing compiler required member 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute..ctor'

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a project targeted to .Net 4.0. It used to build till yesterday. I looked at code and referenced assemblies. I can see the Extension attribute defined. Anyone has any clue about it.

I referred following questions but no help 
- ["Missing compiler required member" error being thrown multiple times with almost no changes to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182644/missing-compiler-required-member-error-being-thrown-multiple-times-with-almost)

[image]

[image]

*** UPDATE 1: ***
I see Npgsql is defining ExtensionAttribute in the same namespace. When I removed and added older version of Npgsql, it built. What should I do to use latest Npgsql?

[image]

Comment: Did you change target 4.0 -> 4.5? or referenced 4.5x assembly?

Comment: Had similar issue when my .net4 project referenced a .net3.5 assembly, and both of them have defined extension methods.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, No change in target. All assemblies are of 4.0 or less

Comment: @AlexSkalozub, you are right I inspected all referenced assemblies. Please see my update 1

Comment: They have libs for different .net versions from 2.0 to 4.5. Using the correct one should fix your problem. If you added it with nuGet, then try re-adding the package.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub, that is the answer. Somebody in my team must have added a version that is compiled against 2.0 to our internal repo. I added a new one targeted to 4.0 and it worked. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me recently, and my research kept coming back to problems with JSON.Net not targeting the correct version.

If you are using it, I would suggest removing it from your references, and removing the lines from your packages.config that also reference it. Then re-install it through NuGet and compile.